# How to find entities from some index to some index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongo and using it in my nodejs application. I have a huge collection of entities. Out of which I have to find that entries from a specific array. I can find all the entities as :

```
dataModel.find({}, function(err, entities){
    if(err){
      res.json({message: err})
    }

    console.log(entities);
    res.json({entities});
  });
```

and then return a few (fromIndex to toIndex) which is highly un-optimized. How can I find only from `fromIndex` to `toIndex`.

**[Edit: ]**
Suppose I have an entities array in database which is 10,000 in length and I need to find only first 10 entries and then upon user request the next entries and so on (pagination in UI), so what I can do is find all entries and return the first 10 (or some 10) which is not optimized. Is there anything like `findFromIndex` function which takes size of chunk (like 10) and returns only those 10 entries in the array?

Comment: No idea what this means. How about sharing a small sample document to illustrate, and and expected result to extract? Please

Comment: @NeilLunn edited the question